# Fetching data from mysql in two different columns (div) on a website

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've a question about fetching data from MySQL database to a website. On the website I have two columns (or div) where I need to put the data.

In the database I have a row (column) called 'options'. The users filled in the form and for the 'options' (radio button) they had to choose between 'right' and 'wrong'.

So now I would like to fetch the data so that all the people who chosen 'right' goes in the first column on the left side. And all the people who chosen 'wrong' goes in the second column on the right side.

I don't know how to seperate the data in two columns (div) on a website.

I have the following script:

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name_comment","Pass");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("name_comment", $con);
$article_id = $_GET['id'];
if( ! is_numeric($article_id) )
die('invalid article id');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id LIMIT 0 , 30";
$comments = mysql_query($query);
echo "<h1>User Comments</h1>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $options = $row['options'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $options = htmlspecialchars($row['options'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
    echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
    Name: $name<br />
    Options: $options<br />
    Email: $email<br />
    Website: $website<br />
    Comment: $comment<br />
    Timestamp: $timestamp
    </div>
    ";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You have two ways of doing it first you can make two div and call with their ids. In first div you can write php script for right option and in second div you can write php for wrong option. And the second is using table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing it :

The first one : you sort your users in two categories and then display each category in the corresponding div :

```
// sorting users in two categories
$users = array(
    'right' => array(),
    'wrong' => array();
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $users[$row['comment']][] = $row;
}

//displaying them 
foreach($users['right']) as $row){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $options = $row['options'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $options = htmlspecialchars($row['options'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
    echo "<h1>Right</h1>";
    echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
    Name: $name<br />
    Options: $options<br />
    Email: $email<br />
    Website: $website<br />
    Comment: $comment<br />
    Timestamp: $timestamp
    </div>
    ";
}

foreach($users['wrong']) as $row){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $options = $row['options'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $website = $row['website'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $options = htmlspecialchars($row['options'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
    echo "<h1>Wrong</h1>";
    echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
    Name: $name<br />
    Options: $options<br />
    Email: $email<br />
    Website: $website<br />
    Comment: $comment<br />
    Timestamp: $timestamp
    </div>
    ";
}
```

The second one : you perform two queries and display them :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id AND comment='right' LIMIT 0 , 30";
$comments = mysql_query($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id AND comment='wrong' LIMIT 0 , 30";
$comments = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to save DB data in two array one will consist record having 'right' option and other one will have wrong records and then iterate loop separately for those two array to create left and right divs. And give css accordingly. Please refer snippet for more understanding.

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name_comment","Pass");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("name_comment", $con);
$article_id = $_GET['id'];
if( ! is_numeric($article_id) )
die('invalid article id');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id LIMIT 0 , 30";
$comments = mysql_query($query);

echo "<h1>User Comments</h1>"; 
$rightValues = [];
$wrongValues = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  if($row['options']=='right'){
    $rightValues[] = $row;
  }else if($row['options']=='wrong'){
    $wrongValues[] = $row;
  } 
}

//Div with right values
//Left side Div
foreach($rightValues as $row){
  $name = $row['name'];
  $options = $row['options'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $website = $row['website'];
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $options = htmlspecialchars($row['options'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
  //Give Css such a way that this div will display on the left side
  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
  Name: $name<br />
  Options: $options<br />
  Email: $email<br />
  Website: $website<br />
  Comment: $comment<br />
  Timestamp: $timestamp
  </div>
  ";
}

//Div with wrong values
//Right side Div
foreach($wrongValues as $row){
  $name = $row['name'];
  $options = $row['options'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $website = $row['website'];
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $options = htmlspecialchars($row['options'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $website = htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
  //Give Css such a way that this div will display on the right side
  echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
  Name: $name<br />
  Options: $options<br />
  Email: $email<br />
  Website: $website<br />
  Comment: $comment<br />
  Timestamp: $timestamp
  </div>
  ";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create two new array say **left** and **right**. Push the `$row`  array to the corresponding array and echo the data in the corresponding div

```
$left=[];
$right=[];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 if($row["option"]=="right"){ // right is just an assumption. Replace with the real data
        $left[]=$row;
    }else{
        $right[]=$row;
    }
}

echo '<div id="left">';
foreach($left as $data){
    echo 'Name: '.$data["name"].'<br />
          Options: '.$data["options"]'.<br />'; 
// continue
}
echo '</div>';
//similarly for right div using $right array
```

Answer (score 0):

Took too long to answer, but another approach. One thing I would say is that there is no point creating the db connection if the supplied `id` is not numeric, so place that code after the relevant checks.

```
<?

    $right = $wrong = array();
    $article_id = $_GET['id'];
    if( !is_numeric( $article_id ) ) die('invalid article id');

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","name_comment","Pass");
    if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("name_comment", $con);



    $query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articleid` =$article_id LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $comments = mysql_query( $query );
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $comments, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){

        $data=(object)array(
            'name'      =>  htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES),
            'email'     =>  htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES),
            'website'   =>  htmlspecialchars($row['website'],ENT_QUOTES),
            'comment'   =>  htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES),
            'timestamp' =>  htmlspecialchars($row['timestamp'],ENT_QUOTES)
        );

        /* 
            Assumed that the column holds boolean 1/0, 
            otherwise change logic here according to 
            data in the column.
        */
        if( intval( $row['options'] ) )==1 ) $right[]=$data;
        else $wrong[]=$data;
    }
    mysql_close($con);



    echo "<h1>User Comments</h1>"; 

    /* process RIGHT answers */
    echo "<div id='right'>";
    foreach( $right as $row ){
        echo "
        <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
            Name: {$row->name}<br />
            Options: {$row->options}<br />
            Email: {$row->email}<br />
            Website: {$row->website}<br />
            Comment: {$row->comment}<br />
            Timestamp: {$row->timestamp}
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";




    /* Process WRONG answers */
    echo "<div id='wrong'>";
    foreach( $wrong as $row ){

        echo "
        <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
            Name: {$row->name}<br />
            Options: {$row->options}<br />
            Email: {$row->email}<br />
            Website: {$row->website}<br />
            Comment: {$row->comment}<br />
            Timestamp: {$row->timestamp}
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

?>
```